# Cryptic events in MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, ms-access, centos

I connect to the master side with ODBC and control data from Access.

I inserted the test table from the access to the master, and confirmed what the data was synchronized to the slave side.

Somehow, the field set by int (8) (primary key) and tinyint (1) is the slave side 48 added value.
On the master, the field set by tinyint (1) is smallint (6) on slave.

If I manipulate the table from the console or phpmyadmin, the definition is reflected correctly on the slave as it is.

MySQL Connector version is 5.3.8.

Comment: the slide side 48 added value - ??

Comment: This is unclear and certainly not reproducible. Imagine that you are talking to someone who knows nothing about your particular installation. What would we need to know in order to help you?

Comment: Sorry,It was a slave side mistake.